# How to use Key {Key:pair} passed from Python to SQL server query

Tags: python, sql-server

We use Reliance `ETQ Product`.
**Python code** -

```
Dict = {'USdateFrom':Rdate.getUSFormatDateOnly(dateFrom,Rdate.MEDIUM),'USdateTo':Rdate.getUSFormatDateOnly(dateTo,Rdate.MEDIUM)}
Rutilities.debug(Rdate.getUSFormatDateOnly(dateFrom,Rdate.MEDIUM))
dao = thisApplication.executeQueryFromDatasource("SQL server query file",Dict)
```

This code calls SQL server query file which has below `SQL`.

**SQL server code - SQL server query file**

```
SELECT * from <Table>
WHERE
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(TABLE_DATE AS DATETIME),101)
BETWEEN
CONVERT(VARCHAR,'USdateFrom',101)
AND
CONVERT(VARCHAR,'USdateTo',101)
```

**Query** - `USDateFrom` and `USdateTo` in SQL does not work. No error. How to write correct syntax to be able to get value from variables coming from Python code.

Comment: Didn't get you. You want to use dictionary value and a replacement in python string ?

Comment: I want to pass dictionary key value into sql mentioned. Key is USdateFrom and value is in "Rdate.getUSFormatDateOnly(dateFrom,Rdate.MEDIUM)". Value is Date and it should be recognized by SQL. How do we pass this value in SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` function of python to pass a dictionary to a string

```
sql = """SELECT * from <Table>
WHERE
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(TABLE_DATE AS DATETIME),101)
BETWEEN
CONVERT(VARCHAR,'{USdateFrom}',101)
AND
CONVERT(VARCHAR,'{USdateTo}',101)""".format(**Dict)
```

Let me know if this what you wanted

Comment: Your suggestion will not work inside python script because that query is in separate place and called using this function "thisApplication.executeQueryFromDatasource". I dont know whether sql can be embedded inside python script file. Python script also exists in one formula file. The database is sql server. How can sql server query parse such passed key values into where clause? Any idea?

Comment: Can't you use sql.execute method ?

Comment: By execute means, you are saying to import connector, create cursor, execute then fetch?? All this inside Python script? If yes I have to try. Alternatively, what can we do inside sql query to recognize python sent variable?